# Quelle serait une tournure équivalente à « Il fait tout à moitié » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation, reformulation

Cet éditeur fait tout à moitié, il ne prend pas en considération tous les aspects des questions et des solutions proposées sur les sites de Q&R, parfois il pense qu’une solution est fausse, mais en réalité il s’agit d’une erreur de frappe, c’est un genre d’erreur d’interprétation qui pourrait être évité s’il ne se cantonnait pas qu’à une partie de la solution et qu’il l’étudiait convenablement de la première ligne à la dernière avec application.

N’hésitez à me proposer une reformulation complète de ce texte.

Merci!

Comment: Et toi, quelles autres idées as-tu pour exprimer « faire les choses à moitié ». Déjà [les premières trouvées du premier clic](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/faire-les-choses-a-moitie) : → « N’hésitez à me proposer une reformulation complète de ce texte. »   "We are not a text translation or proofreading service."

Comment: @None: Est-ce que mon texte laisse entendre un impératif, ai-je écrit « None, tu dois faire ce que je t’ai dit? » Non!

Comment: Quand une question ne suscite pas ton intérêt, tu n’as qu’à passer à la suivante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En réalité « faire les choses à moitié » signifie « faire les choses partiellement, pas convenablement » ([réf.](https://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/19843/faire-les-choses-a-moitie/)), et on ne prend donc pas l'expression dans son sens littéral. C'est au moins une raison pour laquelle je crois que l'on peut utiliser à sa place le verbe « *bâcler* ».

- Cet éditeur *bâcle* tout.

> (TLFi) **B.** − Péj., cour. Faire quelque chose à la hâte et sans soin. Anton. fam. fignoler

Dans la langue familière le verbe « *torcher* » exprime la même idée.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/torcher)) **D. 2**. Fam. Exécuter quelque chose très rapidement et sans soin; bâcler. Synon. fam. torchonner.

Le verbe « sabrer » est un autre mot de la même sorte (familier).

---

« Bâcler » est de loin préférable à ces deux derniers si l'on tient à s'exprimer de façon plus élégante.